# Issue in socket reconnection

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have an app that has socket features. I could notice that the app is trying to reconnect frequently when the app is in an idle state. Is there any way that I could maintain a stable connection with the server without reconnections?

Connection drops even though I am receiving pings every 5 seconds. I need the connection to be alive until I close it.

I have configured my server with pingIntervals as below:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    pingInterval: 5000, 
    pingTimeout: 15000
});
```

Client-Side Configuration:

```
io(TENANT_URL, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
    autoConnect: false,
    'reconnection': true,
    'reconnectionDelay': 10000,
    'reconnectionDelayMax': 5000,
    'reconnectionAttempts': 10
});
```

Is there anything that I can do with the configuration to make the connection stable?

Reconnection timings:
[image]

Comment: Do you reply the ping message from server with a pong? If not, then you should try that. Without replying the ping message, the server might think that you have an inactive connection and might close after a while (usually 5 mins, but also depends on the config).

Another thing that might help is that setting an interval on the client side to send ping message to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync the heartBeat timeouts and Intervals in the client side too.

Client-Side

```
io.pingTimeout = 15000
```

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/v3
Just check `Disconnection detection` section to understand it more clearly